# 2x COUNT in HAVING clause

Tags: oracle, count

I have following problem:
I want to count data in one table, count data in second table and compare countings in having clause, and display only that rows which have the same countings
Something like that:

```
SELECT bla
FROM T1 t1 JOIN T2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
HAVING COUNT(counted data from table1) = COUNT(counted data from table2)
```

Do you have any idea?
Cheers

Comment: counting of what ?? select count(*) from T1 will return total number of rows and you cant apply it to check rows from other table, could you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL:

```
SELECT t1.bla, t1.id, t1.counter, t2.counter
  FROM (SELECT t1.bla, t1.id, COUNT(counted_data_from_t1) AS counter
          FROM t1
         GROUP BY t1.bla, t1.id
       ) AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT t2.id, COUNT(counted_data_from_t2) AS counter
          FROM t2
         GROUP BY t2.id
       ) AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.counter = t2.counter
```

Oracle SQL (because Oracle doesn't like AS before table aliases):

```
SELECT t1.bla, t1.id, t1.counter, t2.counter
  FROM (SELECT t1.bla, t1.id, COUNT(counted_data_from_t1) AS counter
          FROM t1
         GROUP BY t1.bla, t1.id
       ) t1
  JOIN (SELECT t2.id, COUNT(counted_data_from_t2) AS counter
          FROM t2
         GROUP BY t2.id
       ) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.counter = t2.counter
```

You just have to decide where `bla` comes from; I nominated `t1`.  I'm assuming that for any given value of `t1.id`, there is a single value of `t1.bla`.  If there isn't, then you need to explain much more clearly what you're counting and where the various columns are, and what the keys of the tables are.

*Update:* Apologies for not noticing the Oracle tag and giving invalid Oracle syntax.

Comment: I did it in your way, but i have an error (Line 5, Column9, SQL Command not properly ended)

    `SELECT jezyki.pseudo_wampira, sprawnosc.counter
      FROM (SELECT pseudo_wampira, COUNT(*) AS counter
              FROM Jezyki_obce_w
             GROUP BY pseudo_wampira
           ) AS jezyki
      JOIN (SELECT pseudo_wampira, sprawnosc, COUNT(*) AS counter
              FROM Sprawnosci_w
             GROUP BY pseudo_wampira, sprawnosc
           ) AS sprawnosc
        ON (jezyki.pseudo_wampira = sprawnosc.pseudo_wampira AND jezyki.counter = sprawnosc.counter)`

Do you see that error?

Comment: Sorry for that i have issues with coding in comments. Code has tabulations like Yours ;5th line is ") AS jezyki"

Comment: @robocoder - Oracle doesn't let you user `AS` for table aliases, though it does for column aliases. Try just removing that word, so line 5 becomes just `) t1` and line 9 `) t2`.

Comment: @AlexPoole: thanks for helping while I was too busy to respond.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH jezyki as 
          (SELECT pseudo_wampira, COUNT(*) AS counter
            FROM Jezyki_obce_w
            GROUP BY pseudo_wampira
          )
    ,sprawnosc as 
         (SELECT pseudo_wampira, sprawnosc, COUNT(*) AS counter
          FROM Sprawnosci_w
         GROUP BY pseudo_wampira, sprawnosc 
         )
      SELECT jezyki.pseudo_wampira, sprawnosc.counter
        FROM jezyki,sprawnosc
       WHERE  jezyki.pseudo_wampira = sprawnosc.pseudo_wampira 
         AND  jezyki.counter = sprawnosc.counter
```